# Wait for next job to finish on a Mac

Tags: macos, bash, bash-scripting

I want to submit a bunch of jobs to run in the background, and pause when I submit a certain number to wait until one finishes to avoid overwhelming the system.  On Linux, I would do

```
x=0
while true
do
  sleep 100 &
  let x=x+1
  if [[ $x -gt 10 ]]
  then
    # Wait for the next job to finish
    wait -n
    let x=x-1
  fi
done
```

This fails on a Mac, where `wait` can take a pid, but not the `-n` argument.

Is there some other way to do this?  Unlike in the example, the jobs are slow but can vary in runtime, so the first one started might not be the first one to finish.  I could wait one the oldest job if there is not a better way, but I would rather wait for the first one to finish.

Comment: When you refer to n, us `$n`.

Comment: Fixed that, although the intent of the sample code was probably clear anyway.  I also renamed the variable to be clear that `-n` wasn't supposed to be using `-$n`, but the "next job to finish" flag.